# How do I make a new InternetExplorerDriver when the driver EXE file doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a working script that runs with Firefox but I cannot invoke any other Webdriver browser:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;            


driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); - an exception is thrown

            //start setup
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseURL = "http://www.google.com";
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
            //end setup
```

I get this error:

```
The IEDriverServer.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please change your question title to something that at least resembles a question

Answer (score 3):

The IEdriver now ships separately as a separate exe as mentioned in the error.  You need to download the driver and add it to the PATH env variable as again mentioned in the error.  Explanation for the separation of the driver [here](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.in/2012/11/are-you-kidding-me-ie-driver-another.html)

More info @ https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

The same is the case for the chromedriver.  You would need to download it separately while for firefox, this is not the case and hence that is the only driver that works for you.